# Mikrotik main IP

Tags: mikrotik

On mikrotik (CCR-1009, v6.0), I use 2 interfaces : eth1 for WAN and eth8 for LAN. 
On LAN interface 2 IPs: 192.168.22.1/24 as main and 10.10.10.1/24 for routing pptp from WAN. I also have some pptp/l2tp and IPSec connections from WAN port. For expamlpe I have IPsec connect, on my side for incoming tunnel IP:192.168.22.1, and on other side 192.168.8.1/24. 
When do traceroute from 192.168.22.xxx to 192.168.8.1 I see next:

```
  1     1 ms     1 ms    <1 мс  10.10.10.1
  2    30 ms    30 ms    30 ms  192.168.8.1
```

Question:
How I understand mikrotik using 10.10.10.1 as IP because it first in sort IPs on LAN interface? Its true? If is it can i change it on 192.168.22.1, for example?

Comment: If the problem still exist, could you please show schematically how does your IS look? With IPSec it is a bit tricky, sometimes you would need to set up a passthrough NAT rule. As well there is an option for marking packets in order to send them to a specific default gateway (if there are more than one).

Comment: What do you mean by "using 10.10.10.1 as IP"?

Answer (score 1):

The mikrotik should answer using the IP from the network he got the package. In your case 192.168.22.1.

The computer you used to do the ping has only one ip on the 192.168.22.X network? or it has another ip on the 10.10.10.X network.

Please, open a terminal and run: ip address print and paste here the result of the command.